# How to check if a partition is mounted as 'noexec'?

Tags: mount

Currently, I'm using `grep '\s/location/\s.*noexec' /proc/mounts`.
(Is that a right way of checking this?)

Comment: That's fine as long as you only need to work on newer versions of Linux.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711158/detecting-that-a-mount-point-has-noexec-set-before-calling-exec-on-a-file) Q/A

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the mount(8) command, which is available out of the box on all Linux and UNIX systems.

If you run `mount` without any additional arguments, it will list all the currently mounted partitions on your system, file system type and any mount options, such as `noexec`, `rw`, or `nosuid`.

Eg:

```
% mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/basement-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Comment: On Linux, I recommend using `/proc/mounts` in preference to `mount`. If `/etc/mtab` is not updated (e.g. because `/` is read-only), the output of `mount` may not be up-to-date. Also, for some options (not `noexec`), `mount` gives you filtered output which can be misleading for some combinations of versions of the kernel and mount (e.g. with the atime-related options).

Comment: To find the partition the file or directory mounts on - df -P file/goes/here | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're running this on Linux, yes, this is fine. It would be a little more robust to check that `noexec` is between commas or at the beginning or end of its column.

```
grep -Eq '^[^ ]+ /location [^ ]+ ([^ ]*,)?noexec[, ]' /proc/mounts
```

This might be clearer in awk:

```
awk -v location="/location" '$2 == location {exit(!($4 ~ /(^|,)noexec($|,)/))} END {exit(2)}'
```